# How do the two occurrences of the word など function in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

One of my life's strangest experiences was unexpectedly ending up in Cairo, where there was a sort of [extremely cheap hotel full of Japanese backpackers](http://www.joho.st/egypt/2001/07/post-10.html), part of which is described below.

> インド方面からずっとやってきた人や、アフリカを中心に回っている人など、さまざまで、周辺の国への渡航方法なども、ここを訪れれば、かなり情報得られると思う。

I can understand how most of that works, but how does the word など function here? Is it used when giving a list of examples?

Comment: Related: [How to say, “things like”](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2296/542)

Comment: Related: [Combining に/で particles with 等(or other “etc.” stand-ins)](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2347/542)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

など functions like "etc."  You can see it commonly at the end of a list to indicate "other stuff like this" without having to exhaustively list every item out.